# How to make React component return a javascript Node Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, jsx

I'm trying to add a component as an Overlay on my map, but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Here is my code:

```
insertPoint(data) {
    var cord = ol.proj.transform([data.lng, data.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    this.potosVeiculos[data.id] = new ol.Overlay({
        position: cord,
        element: <VeiculosMap id={data.id} user_niv_id={data.user_niv_id} lat={data.lat} lng={data.lng} apelido={data.apelido} niv={data.niv} ignicao={data.ignicao} voltagem={data.voltagem} velocidade={data.velocidade} qualidade_sinal={data.qualidade_sinal} sinal={data.sinal} data_atualizacao={data.data_atualizacao} />,
        positioning: 'bottom-center',
        offset: [12,12]
    });
    map.addOverlay(potosVeiculos[data.id]);
    map.render();
}
```

If I do the following, it works:

```
insertPoint(data) {
    var cord = ol.proj.transform([data.lng, data.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    this.potosVeiculos[data.id] = new ol.Overlay({
        position: cord,
        element: document.createElement('div'),
        positioning: 'bottom-center',
        offset: [12,12]
    });
    map.addOverlay(potosVeiculos[data.id]);
    map.render();
}
```

My question is, how can I make a React Component return a simple JavaScript Node?

Comment: Can you post the code of your `VeiculosMap` component?

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach to a JavaScript node because those don't exist within HTML. OpenLayers renders to HTML elements. You need to create a ref to whichever HTML node you want to attach to.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your answer? I read the documentation you linked, but I didn't understand how to use refs in my case.